# jQuery function bounces element - not very smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jQuery plugin on my website. ( http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/plugin-slide-demo.html ). Now if you closely examine the demo slider, you will see a slight bump/bounce at the bottom every time a header element opens. Now I have the same problem on my website except the bounce is much worse.

How can I minimize/eliminate that effect? the initialization code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('UL.drawers').accordion({
        // the drawer handle
        header: 'H2.drawer-handle',

        // our selected class
        selectedClass: 'open',

        // match the Apple slide out effect
        event: 'mouseover'
    });
});
```

Also how can I change the above code so that the 'drawer' **closes** when I do not hover over any header element(tab).

Thank You

Comment: ok i read over the plugin and i guess the problem is the different interpretation of .outerHeight() and innerHeight()... go into the plugin and alert theese heights and look in browsers if theres a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say without code to test, but it could be a case of the [jQuery animation jump problem](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/animation-jump-quick-tip/).